# How to remove an array of items from an array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to remove user IDs in a column for this table called Offer. User IDs are inserted in as a string like '1,2,3,4'. I have a select multiple which contains a list of approved users for the offer in the table. I am having trouble removing an array of userId's from this column field. My code for the function is below:

```php
Public function removeAccess(Offer $offer, Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'private_access' => 'required',
    ]);

    $current_allowed = array($offer->private_allowed);
    $remove_allowed = $request->private_access;
    $allowed = array_diff_key($current_allowed, array_flip($remove_allowed));
    $offer->private_access = $allowed;
    $offer->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Publisher(s) successfully removed from private access.');
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought I would do a loop of each of the `$request->private_access` and then check if it's in the array, if it is, deletes it. I found another code elsewhere online to do it how I have it displayed, but still running into issues with it deleting all of them even if I select only 1 from the < select multiple > input.

Question Solved! After more research and another 24 hours of on-and-off figuring this out, below is the function now that works for the task.

Important for anyone encountering the same issue, in the select, I had to add [] behind the name-"name[]" to put the values into an array> I also had to convert my array in the database to be similar to the array the multiple select comes with.

```php
    $this->validate($request, [
        'private_access' => 'required',
    ]);

    $current_allowed = explode(',', $offer->private_access);
    $remove_allowed = $request->private_access;
    $filtered = array_diff($current_allowed, $remove_allowed);
    $allowed = implode(',', $filtered);
    $offer->private_access = $allowed;
    $offer->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Publisher(s) successfully removed from private access.');
}
```

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors('An error has occurred.');
```

Comment: I'm confused so correct me if I'm wrong. So you have a table name `Offer`  and there is a column that contains the `user ids` which means that for every row there is a `userid` column that contains `1,2,3,4` as a string like `| 1 | 1,2,3,4 |`

Comment: @xenooooo - Correct!

Comment: Also does the user can also be in the other offer ?

Comment: @xenooooo -  This code is for an offer manage page. This is where an admin can remove currently allowed users to the individual offer.

Comment: _"User IDs are inserted in as a string like '1,2,3,4'."_ - and _that_ is something you should not have done in the first place; see [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/1427878)

Answer (score 0):

i think your code must like this

```
Public function removeAccess(Offer $offer, Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
       'private_access' => 'required',
    ]);
    //make current allowed from db an array
    $current_allowed = explode(",",$offer->private_allowed);
    $remove_allowed = $request->private_access;
    //we must also flip array from database then compare with array_diff_key
    $allowed = array_diff_key(array_flip($current_allowed), array_flip($remove_allowed));
    $offer->private_access = $allowed;
    $offer->save();
    return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Publisher(s) successfully removed from private access.');
    }
```